# How to create custom time range in python from datetime?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have been trying to find a way to create a custom time range that I need for my report.

I have a column with `DateTime` from which I got `weekday`.

I want to create a `daypart` from that `DateTime` which would meet the following criteria:

- If the day is between Monday and Friday, and the time is between 10:00 AM to 3:00 PM then return MF10a-3p, and if it is between 6:00 PM to 10:00 PM, then return `MF6p-10p`, etc.
- For weekends, I want the same time range but `Sa` and `Su` for Saturday and Sunday respectively.

`DateTime` is in the format given below, and `weekday` is Monday. I want to write this `daypart` on a CSV:

```
12/5/2016 3:02
```

Comment: When saying that "12/5/2016 3:02" is the format, I am assuming it is "D/M/Y H(24):M", is that correct? Also, what if it is *not* in the allotted times, and what have you already tried?

Comment: Yes, that is the format. And there is a range for every hour in the clock, I just gave few examples.